# When using str_pad, does Laravel trim white spaces?

Tags: php, laravel

When using str_pad in a laravel blade, I am not getting the expected results when trying to pad with blank spaces:

```
:{{ str_pad($devices['10.0.0.100']['Device_Name'], 25,"**")}}:
```

result

```
:Device********************:
```

but if i try to do spaces it doesn't work the same:

```
:{{ str_pad($devices['10.0.0.100']['Device_Name'], 25)}}:
```

result:

```
:Device :
```

Is laravel doing some trim function in the background? What am I missing?

Comment: I think most browsers do this. You need to use `&nbsp;` in places of space

Comment: By default most HTML elements have the CSS `white-space` property set to `normal`, which is described as: *"Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes."*. That explains nicely why your extra spaces collapse into one. So to fix this, you can either use the non-breaking space entity (`&nbsp`), as suggested by @treyBake, which will not be collapsed, or set that element's `white-space` to `pre` or `pre-wrap`, depending on your layout needs, since both preserve multiple spaces.